# Web app install banner not showing up

Tags: android, google-chrome, service-worker

I have a site (https://adhiyan.in) which, I believe, is meeting all the criteria for web app install banner and yet the banner is not showing up. Can somebody help me find out the reason for it? (I have tried with and without the flag chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks)﻿

```
{
  "short_name": "Adhiyan",
  "name": "Adhiyan Varunkumar",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "/assets/favicons/android-icon-36x36.png",
    "sizes": "36x36",
    "type": "image/png",
    "density": "0.75"
  }, {
    "src": "/assets/favicons/android-icon-48x48.png",
    "sizes": "48x48",
    "type": "image/png",
    "density": "1.0"
  }, {
    "src": "/assets/favicons/android-icon-72x72.png",
    "sizes": "72x72",
    "type": "image/png",
    "density": "1.5"
  }, {
    "src": "/assets/favicons/android-icon-96x96.png",
    "sizes": "96x96",
    "type": "image/png",
    "density": "2.0"
  }, {
    "src": "/assets/favicons/android-icon-144x144.png",
    "sizes": "144x144",
    "type": "image/png",
    "density": "3.0"
  }, {
    "src": "/assets/favicons/android-icon-192x192.png",
    "sizes": "192x192",
    "type": "image/png",
    "density": "4.0"
  }],
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

I am using Chrome for Android stable v44.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. At this point, "start_url" attribute seems to be  mandatory for the banner to show up. I have added "start_url" : "/index.html" for the banner to show up.

Comment: seriously? I thought if you don't have "start_url", then the current page will show the banner...

Comment: It's not a "start_url" for the page to show the banner, it's the starting URL which the "installed" webapp will start at when it's launched through its icon.